# MySQL Master - Master Replication

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-5.5

I have established a master A and master B replication between two servers. Both are getting replicated, but it is limited to only one database.

My questions:

1. How to create a new database in Master A has to replicated in Master B or doing the same in vice versa?
2. Need to Replicate more than one database

Answer (score 1):

Could you give us some info on the replication config in your config files.

For sure if you replicate one db at a time and you need to add one, you won't have a choice to change your config then to restart your instances.

If you can I'll suggest more a full replication. less trouble and if you need to add dbs, there is no problem there.